# VisualSVN Server what Windows Server 2008 roles needed for user to be able to login

Tags: windows, svn, windows-server-2008, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

I have an SVN Server located on a Windows Server 2008 and I have setup my username properly at the SVN level (read/write access rights).

But when trying to access the server via a browser, I get the **You don't have permission to access /svn/project1/ on this server.**

Are they any special Windows Server Roles that I need to setup in order to make this svn user login work?

Answer (score 3):

No special Windows Server roles are required.

You should check what is logged to [VisualSVN Server log](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00028/) when you get the error. 
In most cases, it's enough to double-check permissions in VisualSVN Server Manager (or Repository Configurator if you use one). Keep in mind the fact that paths and access rules are case-sensitive in Subversion, so check the URL you enter in browser.

There is a known bug in VisualSVN Server 2.7 that will be fixed in one of the next patch releases. Authorization configuration file is not created automatically and global permissions don't work when you switch from Subversion authentication to Windows one. In this case you'll see the following error on VisualSVN Server log:

> Failed to load the AuthzVisualSVNReposRelativeAccessFile: Can't open
>   file 'C:\Repositories\MyRepo\conf\VisualSVN-WinAuthz.ini': **The
>   system cannot find the file specified.** (OS 2)

If it's your case, you can go to Security properties of a repository in VisualSVN Server Manager console and add / remove any account from the list. This will force VisualSVN Server to create an empty authorization file and global permissions will start working properly.