# VisualSVN - set up repository and set access to use Basic Windows Authentication - login results in 403?

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

I've set up my repository using VisualSVN Server, imported an existing repostiory, and set the user access rights to use Windows Authentication (Basic). I then try to access the URL of the created repository; after entering my username and password, I am immediately greeted with a 403 Forbidden notice (even though I have specified both Read / Write privileges to myself using VisualSVN Server Manager console).

I've tried using VisualSVN's own username/password combo, and this works successfully. It's only when authenticating via Active Directory, and entering the username and password correctly, that I get this 403 (of course, if I enter it incorrectly, I am prompted for a username and password once more).

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Cheers

Comment: What do you see in VisualSVN Server's eventlog? BTW see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19854000/761095

Answer (score 2):

I guess that when you installed VisualSVN Server you selected Subversion authentication and authorization type and then later switched to Basic Windows authentication. In such case VisualSVN Server does not automatically create a file required to be in each repository's /conf directory "VisualSVN-WinAuthz.ini". This is currently by design for security reasons but the behavior is going to be improved in future releases.

---

So I suggest you to check VisualSVN Server's eventlog:

Start `eventvwr.msc` |  Applications and Services Logs | VisualSVN Server log.

**What error event do you see there?**

If the error is

```
 Failed to load the AuthzVisualSVNReposRelativeAccessFile: Can't open
 file 'C:\Repositories\MyRepo\conf\VisualSVN-WinAuthz.ini': The system
 cannot find the file specified. (OS 2)
```

Then you have to create the file which contains the list of authorization rules. To do this you can go to *Security* properties of a repository in VisualSVN Server Manager console and add / remove any account from the list. This will force VisualSVN Server to create an empty authorization file and global permissions will start working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue but i resolved, kindly find the my below error.

> Failed to load the AuthzVisualSVNSubversionReposRelativeAccessFile: An
>   authz rule refers to group '@ReleaseTeam', which is undefined
>   (220003) APR does not understand this error code
>      192.168.10.131

Error Meaning:

This error shows there is no groups like ReleaseTeam, while we taking backups from existing server  that backups refers some users and groups which we created earlier.

So I suggest you to check VisualSVN Server's eventlog:

Start eventvwr.msc | Applications and Services Logs | VisualSVN Server log.

What error event do you see there?

If the error is:

> Failed to load the AuthzVisualSVNSubversionReposRelativeAccessFile: An
>   authz rule refers to group '@ReleaseTeam (Username or Groups from
>   existing Visual SVN Server)', which is undefined

Steps to follow:

Find the user or group name and Create the same groupname or users in new Visual SVN Server. Try this it will work definitely