# Failed to load the AuthzVisualSVNReposRelativeAccessFile: Can't open file 'VisualSVN-WinAuthz.ini': Access is denied

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

After migrating a repository from an older version of VisualSVN server to a newer version on a fresh machine I see this error message:

`Failed to load the AuthzVisualSVNReposRelativeAccessFile: Can't open file 'C:\PATH_TO\VisualSVN-WinAuthz.ini': Access is denied`

On SOF I have seen solutions to the following error message:

```
Failed to load the AuthzVisualSVNReposRelativeAccessFile: Can't open
 file 'C:\Repositories\MyRepo\conf\VisualSVN-WinAuthz.ini': The system
 cannot find the file specified. (OS 2)
```

Link: [VisualSVN - set up repository and set access to use Basic Windows Authentication - login results in 403?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25041982/visualsvn-set-up-repository-and-set-access-to-use-basic-windows-authentication)

The solution to this question states that the `VisualSVN-WinAuthz.ini` file is missing.

In my case both files (`VisualSVN-WinAuthz.ini` `VisualSVN-WinAuthz.ini`) are present.

The above solution does not work for this error message.

What could cause the "Access is denied" error message?

Answer (score 1):

When you move VisualSVN Server from one computer to another you need to read the article [KB166: Migrating VisualSVN Server to another computer](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00166/).

This `Access is denied` error means that the `VisualSVNServer` service cannot access and read the `VisualSVN-WinAuthz.ini` file (per-repository authz file).

This means that the server's service account (it is Network Service, by default) does not have permissions to read this file, and the permissions have to be fixed. Read the article [KB37: Permissions required to run VisualSVN Server](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00037/).

When your VisualSVN Server runs under the default built-in Network Service account, you can follow these steps to configure permissions automatically:

1. Start the VisualSVN Server Manager console.
2. Navigate to **Action | Properties | Storage**.
3. Uncheck and check back the **Automatically adjust permissions** option. Click **Apply**.

**IMPORTANT:** When you move VisualSVN Server from one computer to another, you have to install the same version that runs on the original server computer. Do not mix upgrade and migration tasks.

Comment: In my case the error was 
Failed to load the AuthzVisualSVNAccessFile: Can't open file '<path to>\\authz-windows': Access is denied.  
(OS 5) Access is denied.  [client xxx]
Access denied: 'User' GET Utilities:/
[client xxx]
VisualSVN Server 2.5
This happened after a windows server hyper-v upgrade (host running svn was not changed or moved). After lots of searching I came across this article and was able to resolve the problem. THANKS!